# How to receive the information which key has been pressed?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, keyboard, detection

I have a tablet with windows 7. The tablet has 5 Buttons (4 function buttons and an enter button) that the user can customize with a tool. In the tool the user can configure the path to a program which shall be started when the button is pressed.

Now I would like to get the information about the pressed button in my own application too. For that I wrote

```
    private void KeyDownPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
       Log.Info("KeyPressed: "+ e.Key.ToString());
    }
```

and in the xaml file I have

```
   <Window
   x:Name="MainWnd"
   KeyUp="KeyDownPressed">
```

So far this works when I connect a normal keyboard to my app. I also get the message when the user presses the enter-button from the tablet. But when I press the function buttons then I don't receive that event.

Is there any other way to listen to a pressed key?